# Simulation on Excel with 6 possibilities with different probabilities

Tags: excel

So I have a table that looks like this

```
Arrival Time Probability
     0           .09
     1           .17
     2           .27
     3           .2
     4           .15
     5           .12
```

And I want excel to randomly create one of the 6 arrival time values based on the given probabilities using RAND(). Is there any way to do this other than to have nested If loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what I came up with.
I would add a column C that calculates the cumulative brackets from 0-1 each digit would represent.  If you start with zero and use formulas to calculate your brackets, you can change the probability if needed in the future.  (formulas in photo below)

For example, arrival time of 0 would be between 0 and .09.

Then you can use use the rand() function in column D to generate your random number between 0 and 1 and add a lookup function in column E, or wherever you like.  Screenshots of the data and formulas:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your probabilities with cumulative probabilities (with a preliminary line for 0) and use `VLOOKUP`, exploiting the fact that `VLOOKUP` finds the closest match:

[image]